# How do I get whatever is after the underscore?

Tags: php

I have this string: `21839547737_10150750480732738`

In PHP,how do I get whatever is **after** the underscore `_`?

Comment: Will there only *ever* be the one underscore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the substr function and the strpos function

```
$string = "21212121312312_11231231231323213";
$afterunderscore = substr($string, strpos($string, "_") + 1);
```

This will give you the information after the underscore

Answer (score 12):

```
$str = '21839547737_10150750480732738';
$parts = explode('_', $str);
$result = $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

This would return everything after the first underscore (your example):

```
$str = '21839547737_10150750480732738';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, '_') + 1);
// Result: 10150750480732738
```

If you have multiple underscores, it will return everything after the *first* underscore:

```
$str = '21839547737_10150750480732738_12342134234';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, '_') + 1);
// Result: 10150750480732738_12342134234
```

If you only want the part after the *last* underscore, use `strrpos` instead:

```
$str = '21839547737_10150750480732738_12342134234';
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '_') + 1);
// Result: 12342134234
```

Comment: For the part after the last underscore, you have it right in your explanation, but your code has strpos instead of strrpos.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
next(explode('_', $string));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from the php.net website, try using strstr

```
<?php
  $string  = '21839547737_10150750480732738';
  $after = strstr($string, '_');
  echo $after; // prints _10150750480732738
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways to do it. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php for more information on the different functions. You can "split" the string at the underscore, you can find the position of the underscore, than use substr to get everything after. Please read through the various string functions to see what the best way is to do it for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is: `_(\d+)`

Use preg_match:
 `preg_match(/_(\d+)/, "21839547737_10150750480732738", $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

Now you have the matches in `$matches`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an assertion will do it. Of course you can use `explode` instead.

```
preg_match('/(?<=_).*/', '21839547737_10150750480732738', $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($pos = strpos($str, '_'))
  $str=substr($str, $pos+1);
if(!$str) $str='';
```

Returns everything after the first underscore or the whole string if there is no underscore.

It returns the correct result even if the underscore is the last character (substr being annoying and returning false instead of the empty string)